# Unsubscribe from timer in rxjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs

Hi I have a timer running which is like it should show a component for 30sec after every 10 seconds. My code is like this`

```
import { timer } from "rxjs";

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log("RECEIVED PROPS");
    if (this.props.venuesBonusOfferDuration === 0) {
      this.subscribe.unsubscribe();
    }

    this.firstTimerSubscription;
    this.secondTimerSubscription;
    // if (this.state.isMounted) {
    if (
      nextProps.showBonusObj &&
      (!nextProps.exitVenue.exitVenueSuccess || nextProps.enterVenues)
    ) {
      // console.log("isMounted" + this.state.isMounted);

      //if (this.state.isMounted) {
      let milliseconds = nextProps.venuesBonusOfferDuration * 1000;
      this.source = timer(milliseconds);
      this.firstTimerSubscription = this.source.subscribe(val => {
        console.log("hiding bonus offer");
        this.firstTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.props.hideBonusOffer();
        this.secondTimerSubscription = bonusApiTimer.subscribe(val => {
          console.log("caling timer" + val);

          this.props.getVenuesBonusOffer(
            this.props.venues.venues.id,
            this.props.uid,
            this.props.accessToken
          );
        });
      });
      //}
    } else {
      try {
        if (this.secondTimerSubscription != undefined) {
          this.secondTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
          console.log("secondTimer UNSUBSCRIBED");
        }
        if (this.firstTimerSubscription != undefined) {
          this.firstTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
          console.log("firstTimer UNSUBSCRIBED");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(
          "error when removing bonusoffer timer" + JSON.stringify(error)
        );
      }
      //}
    }
  }
```

`

Problem is if I try to unsubscribe this * this.firstTimerSubscription* and *this.secondTimerSubscription* like this

```
try {
  if (this.secondTimerSubscription != undefined) {
    this.secondTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    console.log("secondTimerunmount UNSUBSCRIBED");
  }
  if (this.firstTimerSubscription != undefined) {
    this.firstTimerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    console.log("firstTimerunmount UNSUBSCRIBED");
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error bonusoffer timer" + JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

its still prints logs within timer like "hiding bonus offer" and "calling timer".

Can someone please point out the issue. It been a day since am into this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want `on(30s)-off(10s)-on(30s)-off(10s)-....` ?

Comment: yes thats what the intended behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Based on that I created an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you subscribe multiple times (whenever component receives props) and reassign newest subscription to `firstTimerSubscription` or `secondTimerSubscription` references. But doing that, subscriptions does not magically vanish. To see how it works [here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fvkzgg?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100):

```
const source = timer(1000, 1000);

let subscribe;
subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

setTimeout(() => {
  subscribe.unsubscribe();
}, 2000)
```

Even though you unsubscribed, the first subscription keeps emiting. And the problem is that you lost a reference to it, so you can't unsubscribe now.

Easy fix could be to check whether you already subscribed and unsubscribe if so, **before subscribing**:

```
this.firstTimerSubscription ? this.firstTimerSubscription.unsubscribe: false;
this.firstTimerSubscription = this.source.subscribe(...
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a second timer. Just do a interval of 10 seconds. The interval emits the iteration number `1, 2, 3....`. You can use the modulo operator on that tick. Following example code (for example with 1 second interval) prints `true` and `false` in console. After `true` it needs 3 seconds to show `false`. After `false` it needs 1 second to show `true`.

```
interval(1000).pipe(
  map(tick => tick % 4 !== 0),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```